# How to make jQuery's 'filter' function work correctly for SVG nodes?

Tags: jquery, filter, svg, sizzle

Say I have the following SVG and jQuery:

```
<g id="test">
    <rect>
    <text>demo</text>
</g>

$('#test').filter('text').each(function(){
    // do something
});
```

The filter function doesn't work with SVG, probably because jQuery was designed for DOM manipulation, not namespaced SVG.

But how can I adapt jQuery's filter function to accept SVG correctly?

```
Sizzle.filter = function( expr, set, inplace, not ) {
    var match, anyFound,
        old = expr,
        result = [],
        curLoop = set,
        isXMLFilter = set && set[0] && Sizzle.isXML( set[0] );

    while ( expr && set.length ) {
        for ( var type in Expr.filter ) {
            if ( (match = Expr.leftMatch[ type ].exec( expr )) != null && match[2] ) {
                var found, item,
                    filter = Expr.filter[ type ],
                    left = match[1];

                anyFound = false;

                match.splice(1,1);

                if ( left.substr( left.length - 1 ) === "\\" ) {
                    continue;
                }

                if ( curLoop === result ) {
                    result = [];
                }

                if ( Expr.preFilter[ type ] ) {
                    match = Expr.preFilter[ type ]( match, curLoop, inplace, result, not, isXMLFilter );

                    if ( !match ) {
                        anyFound = found = true;

                    } else if ( match === true ) {
                        continue;
                    }
                }

                if ( match ) {
                    for ( var i = 0; (item = curLoop[i]) != null; i++ ) {
                        if ( item ) {
                            found = filter( item, match, i, curLoop );
                            var pass = not ^ !!found;

                            if ( inplace && found != null ) {
                                if ( pass ) {
                                    anyFound = true;

                                } else {
                                    curLoop[i] = false;
                                }

                            } else if ( pass ) {
                                result.push( item );
                                anyFound = true;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                if ( found !== undefined ) {
                    if ( !inplace ) {
                        curLoop = result;
                    }

                    expr = expr.replace( Expr.match[ type ], "" );

                    if ( !anyFound ) {
                        return [];
                    }

                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        // Improper expression
        if ( expr === old ) {
            if ( anyFound == null ) {
                Sizzle.error( expr );

            } else {
                break;
            }
        }

        old = expr;
    }

    return curLoop;
};
```

Comment: Incidentially, the problem may be somewhere else within jQuery's core, but it's so convoluted at times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need to alter the jQuery source, you can use other traversal methods that are compatible with XML.

```
// This works
$("#test").find("text").each(function() {
    // do something
});
```

to keep the current element as well:

```
var svg = $("#test");
svg.find( "text" ).add( svg ).each(function() {
    // do something
});
```

or:

```
var svg = $("#test");
svg.find( "text" ).andSelf().each(function() {
    // do something
});
```

hope that helps. cheers!

Comment: The 'find' function does not include the current element, only it's descendents. I need to include the current element as well as the descendents.

Comment: ah, in that case you can use either andSelf() or add(). edited above.

Answer (score 1):

SVG nodes work fine in jQuery selectors. The problem is that *$('#test').filter('text')* means "give me all nodes with id *test* that are also text nodes."

As keegan indicated, you're looking for the *find()* function, not the *filter()* function.

Comment: Thank you both. That's helped a great deal.