# Filtering by class attribute using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm a bit confused on how filtering works in jQuery. Apparently, these two lines are different:

```
$('svg').filter('.woah')
$('svg[class=woah]')
```

Why is this so?
Here's a simple jsFiddle I cooked up:
http://jsfiddle.net/8MLRE/4/

Comment: There seems to be an issue with the `svg` tag.  If you change them to `div`s then filter works the same.

Comment: Mmm, it seems like some kind of bug or misbehavior with `svg`. This works though `$('svg').filter('class=woah')` or simply `$('svg.woah')` and this too `$('div').filter('.hello')` but for some reason this doesn't work `$('svg').filter('.woah')`

Comment: `.filter` does not seem to work properly with SVG elements. See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7635073/how-to-make-jquerys-filter-function-work-correctly-for-svg-nodes

Answer (score 0):

The first one may plays role of post filter, e.g. you've got 10 elements and would like to leave on with `some_filter_here`.

The second one is a simple selector.

http://jsfiddle.net/8MLRE/10/

So, with `$('svg')` you will get 3 elements, and then filter them with some selector like `[class=woah]` and so one is left. While with `$('svg[class=woah]')` you instantly get the one.

[jQuery filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)

Answer (score 0):

The first one fetches all `svg` elements then filters them using the filter function and returns those who have class `woah`. This is an overhead in my opinion since this functionality can be done in one call.

The second does the same but uses he attribute selector. It's better han the last as it uses only one function call. But here is a better way to get all `svg` elements wih class `woah`.

I believe you want to achieve `$('svg.woah')`